# Change the PHP version in SSH in CPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I've developed a PHP/MySQL system which runs on PHP 7.0 but when I access it to my remote CPanel via SSH and check the php version `php -v` it show that Im using version 5.4 how can I change this to 7.0 for SSH usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, you have running app on php7 and php5 in shell.
Its possible to have different php versions on same server. CLI(in ssh terminal) version can be other then apache's mod_php. If `php -v` shows not the same as webpage's `phpinfo()` function then this is your case. If you not planning to run console scripts(like some jobs in cron), and webpage with `phpinfo()` function shows needed version, all fine. If not, - you need to reconfigure/upgrade your server, doing this vary on distribution. If its not your own server, then only hosting provider can do that, ask him for help, or you may change hosting provider to who provide needed version.

Comment: ok let me talk to my hosting provider to see if it can be done